# Too much disk activity READING event logs

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, performance

On Win 7 SP1 x64, I notice that sometimes the disk gets so busy that Windows becomes unresponsive for minutes at a time. I referenced this [problem on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/496684/win7-x64-unresponsive-for-a-minute-or-so-hd-failing) in the past once. I've since replaced the drive, and the problem persists.

My machine is plenty fast - this shouldn't be happening **to the extent and duration that it is**. The machine should not become **unusable** for 3, 5 minutes after login/startup or during a VM suspend operation. Yes, the machine will be slower as its saving the state of a VM to disk. And yes, if I have too many startup items, booting will take longer. I appreciate your input, but please spare me from the basics - I've been working with computers for almost thirty years now.

Here is the tallied disk activity, done via [Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), during startup (after login):

<sub>(Click for larger view)</sub>
[image]

and when suspending a VMware VM:

<sub>(Click for larger view)</sub>
[image]

As you can see, System.evtx and Application.evtx account for a huge share of disk activity. This would probably go by unnoticed if it were **writing** to the event log, but **reading from the logs should not be what my disk spends the most time doing**. This is not normal, is it? If not, what would be the tool to find out what in the log is being read?

```
CPU:           Intel Core i5-2520M (Sandy Bridge-MB SV, J1)
               2500 MHz (25.00x100.0) @ 797 MHz (8.00x99.7)
Motherboard:   LENOVO 423946U
Chipset:       Intel QM67 (Cougar Point) [B3]
Memory:        8192 MBytes @ 664 MHz, 9.0-9-9-24
Drive:         ST320LT007, 312.6 GB, Serial ATA 3Gb/s (SSHD Hybrid)
```

Comment: What size are the log files in question? The default for Windows 7 is 20MB if I'm not mistaken.